# Querying Microsoft Academic graph by fields of study of references

Tags: json, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I've been playing around with the Microsoft Academic API, trying to do graph queries using JSON formatted queries. I'm at the point where I think I can produce results, but for some reason I don't get the full set of results.

The query I am attempting to perform will retrieve all papers that reference a paper that has a FieldOfStudy that is one of the ones I'm looking for. Essentially, I'm trying to find out how well cited a field of study is.

I think the query should look something like this:

```
{
  "path": "/paper/ReferenceIDs/reference/FieldOfStudyIDs/field",
  "paper": {
    "type": "Paper",
    "match" : {
        "PublishYear": 2017
    },
    "select": ["DOI","OriginalTitle","PublishYear"]
  },
  "reference" : {
    "type" : "Paper",
    "select" : "OriginalTitle"
  },
  "field": {
    "type": "FieldOfStudy",
    "select": [ "Name" ],
    "return": { "id": [106686826,204641814] }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I get only an incomplete subset of results. Funnily enough though, if I further restrict the initial node by matching on a title, I get another set of results (disjoint from the first query result set)

```
{
  "path": "/paper/ReferenceIDs/reference/FieldOfStudyIDs/field",
  "paper": {
    "type": "Paper",
    "match" : {
        "OriginalTitle": "cancer",
        "PublishYear": 2017
    },
    "select": ["DOI","OriginalTitle","PublishYear"]
  },
  "reference" : {
    "type" : "Paper",
    "select" : "OriginalTitle"
  },
  "field": {
    "type": "FieldOfStudy",
    "select": [ "Name" ],
    "return": { "id": [106686826,204641814] }
  }
}
```

So, what could be going on here? Is the query giving up because the very first node it hits on the broader search doesn't match the path? Is it even possible to query all papers published in a year like this?

Comment: Would you consider accepting an answer with `evaluate` or do you want to solve this using the graph search?

Comment: I'm open to whatever API/search methods that work!